# How start a new line in Yasnippet, with the comment?

Tags: yasnippet

**Q**: how do I get yasnippet to insert the comment sign, when I press return to start new line?

For example, my snippet looks like this

```
         ;; $1 .
         ;; / END 
         $2
```

When the cursor is on the $1, and I'm typing some text, I would like to press return.
 It will start a new line, but the `;;` is missing on the new line.

I found nothing on this specific issue. I could also use elisp forms to create a new mapping on the new line, like (concat comment-start), but it's not clear to me how to expand them appropriately.

See the comment below.

Comment: Are you talking about after expanding the snippet, or while writing the snippet? Does hitting `M-j` (`indent-new-comment-line`) give you behavior that you want?

Comment: Nanny, your comment is appreciated.. but no, when I'm calling `(indent-new-comment-line)` inside the snippet, it will begin a new line, but without comment tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I created a function to solve this, I looked into the Lisp documentation about comment strings and Yasnippet bindings. What about this one:

```el
(defun foo-bar ()
  (interactive)
  (newline)
  (insert (concat comment-start) " ")
  )

(eval-after-load 'yasnippet
  '(progn
     (define-key yas-keymap (kbd "<return>") 'foo-bar)))
```

Comment: I prefer double comment tag ;; instead ;, I got only one. But your solution works anyway.